# телеграмм бот не работает, просто ничего не происходит при запуске

Tags: python, telebot, бот, telegram

```
import config
import telebot

token = '*токен спец вырезал'

bot = telebot.TeleBot(token)

@bot.message_handler(content_types=["text"])
def report():
    if message.text.lower() == 'Привет':
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'привет!')
    else: 
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'пока!')

bot.polling(none_stop = True, interval = 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

у вас в аргументе функции **report** должен принимать message

```py
    def report(message):
```

так же должен быть отступ после `if message.text.lower() == 'Привет':`

Comment: к моменту вашего ответа я уже сам разобрался но всё равно огромное спасибо!

Comment: рад помоч))))))

Answer (score 0):

```
import config
import telebot

token = '*токен спец вырезал'

bot = telebot.TeleBot(token)

@bot.message_handler(content_types=["text"])
def start_message(message):
    if message.text.lower() == 'Привет':
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'привет!')
    else: 
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'пока!')

bot.polling(none_stop = True, interval = 0)
```

Должно заработать